# Can a loop mount a partition that is on the device I will be mounting from?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

For example: I have an external HDD and wish to mount the "backup data" partition so that it appears as a separate device, just for coolness.

Comment: So you have your external harddisk, let's say `/dev/sdb`, and you want that `/dev/sdb2` (your backup data partition) is shown as `/dev/sdc2`? Or aren't you talking about device files?

Comment: What I'm aiming for as an MBR table setup is something like ... /dev/sda: external HDD I'm booting from.  /dev/sda1: "/" partition - boot flag, /dev/sda2: swap partition, /dev/sda3: backup data partition.  My question is, can I mount /dev/sda3 so that it appears as if I am loop mounting a file - e.g. can I do `mkdir -p /mnt/disk` and then `mount -o loop /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk`

Comment: You can definitely do `mkdir -p /mnt/disk` and then `mount -o loop /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk` (`mount` will show the line: `/dev/sda3 on /tmp/mnt type ext3 (rw,loop=/dev/loop0)`, `losetup -a` will say: `/dev/loop0: [XXXX]:YYYY (/dev/sda3)`)... But I'm still at a loss as to what you are trying to achieve with this (apart from the coolness you mention, that is...).

Comment: Yeah, coolness is pretty much it.  I want it to look like the backup partition is a separate drive.  Mostly for showing-off purposes...